# Update table with join in mysql

Tags: php, mysql

i want to update field in my database.
I have two table and table field like bellow

**Table**  `operations_per_assembly` **Field**  `operation_id,is_mecahnical`

**Table**  `operations` **Field**  `id,repair_type_id`

Now i want to update `is_mechanical` field where `repair_type_id` = **3**

**My query**

```
 UPDATE 
  `operations_per_assembly` 
   JOIN `operations` 
     ON `operations`.`id` = `operations_per_assembly`.`operation_id` 
   SET `operations_per_assembly`.`is_mechanical` = '4' 
   WHERE `operations_per_assembly`.`operation_id` = `operations`.`id` 
   AND `operations_per_assembly`.repair_type_id = 3
```

Please help me.

Comment: what do you expect to happen, and what actually happens?

Comment: i have edited question please check.

Comment: `I have make several query but not working` ... OK but _what_ is not working?

Comment: this query run perfectly but  data not update

Comment: _this query run perfectly but data not update_ - Given that it isn't updating the data, I would argue its not running perfectly at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the repair_type_id = 3 condition in the join conditions. This way you are telling to join only on repair_type_id = 3 so you will only get those records.

```
  UPDATE 
  `operations_per_assembly` 
   JOIN `operations` 
     ON `operations`.`id` = `operations_per_assembly`.`operation_id` AND `operations`.repair_type_id = 3
   SET `operations_per_assembly`.`is_mechanical` = '4'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE `operations_per_assembly` a
JOIN `operations` b
   ON a.operation_id = b.id
SET a.is_mechanical = '4' 
WHERE codition (user proper condition)
```

Comment: Please, always give some explanation and not only the plain code

Answer (score 0):

In the `WHERE` clause you are using `operations_per_assembly`.`repair_type_id` but your `operations_per_assembly` table does not have `repair_type_id` in it.

So try the below query:

```
UPDATE `operations_per_assembly` PAS
JOIN `operations` OPE ON OPE.`id` = PAS.`operation_id`
SET PAS.`is_mechanical` = '4'
WHERE OPE.repair_type_id = 3
```